# Generic Adapter with search and sort functionality

Tags: java, android

> I have tried to create a **GenericAdapter** that can help you `search, sort` automatically without writing a lot of code.

But in order to use this you have to follow some rules. How can I make it better and where am I not using a better approach.

rules for using GenericAdapter.

1. extends your business model with BaseModel
2. extends your viewHolder with BaseViewHolder
3. your adapter must extends GenericAdapter

where

**BaseModel.class**

```
public abstract class BaseModel<T> implements Comparator<T>
{
   public abstract String getAttributeToSearch();
   ///public abstract int whatYouWantToCompare();
}
```

**BaseViewHolder.class**

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder<T extends BaseModel> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
{

  public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
  }

  public abstract void bindData(T data);
}
```

**GenericBaseAdapter.class**

```
public abstract class GenericBaseAdapter<T extends BaseModel, U extends BaseViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<U> implements Filterable {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<T> itemList;
    private List<T> origList;

    public GenericBaseAdapter(Context mContext, List<T> itemList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.origList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(U holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(itemList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public T getItem(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.origList = itemList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (origList == null)
                    origList = new ArrayList<>(itemList);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (origList != null && origList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final T cd : origList) {
                            if (cd.getAttributeToSearch().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size();//newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = origList;
                    oReturn.count = origList.size();//newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                itemList = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<T>) results.values);
                // FIXME: 8/16/2017 implement Comparable with sort below
                ///Collections.sort(itemList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public void sortItems(T obje) {
        Collections.sort(itemList, obje);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

for sorting use

```
mAdapter.sortItems(productList.get(0));
```

for searching..

```
mAdapter.getFilter().filter("any string to search");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions take what you like from it:

- You can make `BaseModel` an interface. This gives the added benefit that your models do not need to extend your abstract class.
- In your `getFilter` method in a code review I'd ask you to put curly braces around your first `if`.

  `if (origList == null) {
      origList = new ArrayList<>(itemList);
  }`
- You can instantiate your filter once as a member of the class, rather than instantiating a new one every time the function `getFilter` is called.
- Use [collections.unmodifiablelist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) to protect yourself from unwanted mutations of the original list, when creating or assigning a new list. This is just a precautionary suggestion that has performance implications. Your not mutating when you should not be.

Comment: After converting my BaseModel to interface . My adapter should be like T implements BaseModel . Am I right

Comment: No, still just ```extends``` keyword in that case.

Comment: and in getFilter you are talking about new Filter() or the list (origList ) I created each time

Comment: ```new Filter()```

Comment: you should try this https://github.com/manojbhadane/GenericAdapter/